# JQM mobileinit - seems not global initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I found that mobileinit event fired only after placing handler between jquery and jquery-mobile scripts as below:

```
<script src="jQuery/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).on("mobileinit", function(){
        $.mobile.a = "It works!";
        alert($.mobile.a);
    });
</script>
<script src="jQuery/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js">
</script>
```

Ok, no problem.
But when I trying to inspect `$.mobile.a` on other physical JQM pages - it's undefined.
So, mobileinit in this case is not global initilization - just page init.

What's wrong? How to get mobileinit worked?

Comment: `mobileinit` fires once only.

Comment: The question is not about firing mobileinit - I described how it is fired once.
My question is - changes made inside mobileinit have limited scope - on page where mobileinit fired $.mobile.a has value "It works!", on other pages it's undefined. So, I see mobileinit doesn't work PROPERLY

Comment: You use separate/multi-html files?

Comment: Yes, my web app contains multiple files

Comment: then you need to add the same event for each file. However, if you add it to a file and called that file as `dialog`, the event will be neglected. Because jQM loads elements inside `<body>` only, as a `dialog`.

Comment: So, there still no difference between mobileinit and page ready. Is it possible to have init fired once for session?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29533/discussion-between-omar-and-valery-bulash)

Comment: At which event you are trying to access the `$.mobile.a` in other pages?

Comment: At event pagebeforeshow. Also with many other event - result the same - scope for extension of $.mobile is just one physical page

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an "on" when you need to do a "bind".  i.e.

```
$(document).bind('mobileinit', function () {
$.mobile.a = "It works!";
});
```

The mobileinit happens before the page is rendered so your "alert" won't work as you have it.
The way you had it the var will only be available on that page if at all.
Change the code to bind and now add the alert to the page itself then you should see an alert with "It works!"